# Anki - Specify columns at beginning of import file, including notetype

Tags: anki

I am trying to import a text file with notes and want to be able to decide note by note which deck and notetype each note goes to. So I have a first row in the txt file as follows to specify in which column of the txt file the deck and notetype is specified (I also provide a self-created ID field for easier correction):

```
#columns:id     front   back    deck    notetype
```

I then provide the actual note in this format (I use tabs to separate but show | here to make it easier to read).

| Portu_TyGramSent00001 | I speak Portuguese. | Falo português.|Portuguese::Portu_TyGramSent | CultureRandom |

When I click on import on the Anki decks page, and select the file, the import window correctly shows the rows aligned with the column specified in the first bit of the window, but the Import Options section shows the wrong notetype and the Field Mapping section is also wrong (see image), and when I click on import it seems to be that it is the Field Mapping that actually controls how the upload works. So it is all messed up. What am I doing wrong?
[image]